# Loading multiple audio files did not work as expected

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

On Firefox, Desktop Chrome, Safari browsers, this snippet works fine:

```
snd1 = new Audio("sound1.mp3");
snd1.play();

snd2 = new Audio("sound2.mp3");
snd2.play();
```

But on the Chromecast, snd2 will not play.  After some experimenting, it seemed Chromecast would not allow to load more than one audio file.

Is this behavior by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use more than one audio unless you use [Web Audio](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) APIs, See also this [post](https://plus.google.com/117916055521642810655/posts/3Fq5jcbxipJ).